# insertMapObject Function Android Returning 23 code Cartotype

Tags: android

Firstly, Cartotype provides API for providing the Map in Android,iOS and other platforms  as per my knowledge .

from the docs i found a function that meets my need

```
native int com.cartotype.Framework.insertMapObject  (   int     aMapHandle,
int     aMapObjectType,
String  aLayerName,
Geometry    aGeometry,
String  aStringAttributes,
int     aIntAttribute,
long    aId,
boolean     aReplace 
)
```

But the parameters they refer to i couldn't be successful in getting those and finally got as

```
// Second or continuing measurement, add to arrays
// and draw line
iDistanceMeasurementX = extendArray(
iDistanceMeasurementX, thisPoint[0]);
iDistanceMeasurementY = extendArray(
iDistanceMeasurementY, thisPoint[1]);

// _thread.iFramework.deleteMapObjects(0,
// ID_MEASUREMENT_TOOL, ID_MEASUREMENT_TOOL, null);
// _thread.iFramework.addLineOrPolygonObject(
// "measurementtool", iDistanceMeasurementX,
// iDistanceMeasurementY,
// Framework.DEGREE_COORDS, null, 0,
// ID_MEASUREMENT_TOOL, false);


//Drawing line geometry
Geometry geometry = new Geometry(Framework.DEGREE_COORDS);
geometry.appendPoint(thisPoint[0],thisPoint[1]);
geometry.beginContour();

 try {
                                int abc = _thread.iFramework.insertMapObject(0, MapObject.LINE_TYPE, "measurementtool", geometry, null, 0,
                                        ID_MEASUREMENT_TOOL, false);
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),abc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

//Drawing line with coordinates
// _thread.iFramework.insertPointMapObject(0,"measurementtool", iDistanceMeasurementX[0],iDistanceMeasurementY[0] ,MapObject.LINE_TYPE, "", 0,
// ID_MEASUREMENT_TOOL, false);
//Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Draw Line ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
getMapAndDraw(); // Inefficient, we are drawing
```

Those 'abc' int returns a value 23 and needs to be 0,if success according to the docs.

**MY NEED IS DRAW A LINE b\w 2 Coordinates**

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Graham

```
geometry = new Geometry(Framework.DEGREE_COORDS);

   iDistanceMeasurementX = extendArray(
                                    iDistanceMeasurementX, thisPoint[0]);
                            iDistanceMeasurementY = extendArray(
                                    iDistanceMeasurementY, thisPoint[1]);
geometry.appendPoint(iDistanceMeasurementX[iDistanceMeasurementX.length-1], iDistanceMeasurementY[iDistanceMeasurementY.length-1]);

                            //Drawing line geometry

                                _thread.iFramework.insertMapObject(0, MapObject.LINE_TYPE, "measurementtool", geometry, null, 0,
                                        0, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it seems that only one point is being added to the Geometry object. You need two points to draw a line. Also, the call to beginContour is not needed.

But you mentioned that you're getting the 'duplicate object' error (23). That's because more than one object has been inserted with the id ID_MEASUREMENT_TOOL. By the way, you can get a reference to the CartoType error code constants for Android here:

http://www.cartotype.com/assets/android_api_doc/classcom_1_1cartotype_1_1_error.html